# Phonegap geolocation not working on first click

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I have used to geo: uri for opening the map of the given lat,long in the native application. I have tested in android but the following issue comes up: when the link is clicked for the first time, it opens the current location of the user but when the same link is clicked the second time, it seems to work as expected.

the code is as simple as follows:

```
var url = device.platform == 'Android' ? 'geo:'+Lat+','+Long+"?q="+Lat+','+Long+'('+Name+')'
```

the complete javascript code is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', dready,false);

    function dready()
    {
       $("#SearchResults").html(sessionStorage.Business);
        var url = device.platform == 'Android' ? 'geo:'+sessionStorage.BusinessLat+','+sessionStorage.BusinessLong+"?q="+sessionStorage.BusinessLat+','+sessionStorage.BusinessLong+'('+ sessionStorage.BusinessName+')' : 'comgooglemaps://'+sessionStorage.BusinessLat+','+sessionStorage.BusinessLong;

        $("#MapLink").attr('href',url);
    }
```

as said, the cords are set properly but show up when clicked the second time and not first

Comment: when the link is clicked the first time, it opens the location of the user/device and not the actual co-ords provided. however it works as expected when the link is clicked the second time and so forth.

Comment: Can you provide more code around how you are setting the lat/long coords?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Google Maps only registers the coords the second time you call the geo URI... Please assist?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.  A little hacky, but works.

```
setTimeout(function(){ if(Lat === 0){ location.reload(); }  }, 1000);
```

Basically saying, if your latitude is equal to 0 (fail on getting cords) reload the page.  It is in setTimeout 1 second to make sure the call is made.